# Random private Chat using firebase, algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, firebase, chat

I need help with an algorithm,
I have an arraylist of users, I created a random function to find to each user a random person to chat with,

now here when problem begin, lets say that my list has person A,person B and person C.

if person A and person B search for a user to chat with at the same time, a clashing might happend if A find B ,but B find C.
so B and C will begin chatting but since A found B at the same time, the chat of B and C will be close and instead there will be only chat between A and B.

I dont want such situation to happend, instead I want that if A found B ,B will get into a chat with A immidiatly, instead of finding C and creating this all situation.

please help me solve that issue,

my program has 3 activities, the Landing activity(where someone can find you but you dont search anyone untill u click on search a chat),the searching activity(which is the issue if 2 enters it at the same time as i written above, and the chat activity).

thank you very much and hope you understood it...

Comment: Why can't people chat with multiple other people? Seems like a poor design to close a chat room if someone else starts to chat with you

Comment: @cricket_007 i dont want them to chat with multype, i want it to be 1 on 1,  thats the exact issue,i want that if im A and i found B ,B wont find C, and instead get into the chat with me

Comment: But if B finds C quicker than A finds B, then what? Throw an error?

Comment: @cricket_007 well the issue is when A and B search, and A finds B,but B finds C. B will get into a chat with C, but then the chat iwll close automaticly beacuse A will find B and leave C alone with himself. i dont want such situation to happend.

Comment: Right. So you have three users. Someone is going to be left alone, yes? In that scenario, it'll either be A because B is "not available" or C because B was "taken away". Those are two options that are up to you to decide. There's no solution to get all people chatting for an odd number of people.

Comment: You can add a property to the user called isChatting, and set it to true for both A and B if A finds B. But only do so if B.isChatting is false.